# Bundle Typescript files from dependent module for debugging purposes in Next.js app

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, next.js, ecmascript-5

I have a project written in Typescript that uses Next.js and I want to be able to debug it (either in Chrome Dev Tools or in Intellij).

I'm trying to bundle TS files with webpack embedded in Next.js but it doesn't include TS files from local dependent common library. It only includes JS files which is not sufficient.

My intention is to include all the TS files from workspace by webpack and be able to use source mapping to debug the code in Chrome dev tools.

Also, it's very weird that **index.tsx** from `./pages` folder is not included in bundle. Only its `js` compiled code.

**Used:**

- Next.js 6.1.1
- Typescript 3.8.3
- es5

**next.config.js**

```
const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript')
module.exports = withTypescript({
    poweredByHeader: false,
    webpack: (config, {dev}) => {
        if (dev) {
            config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
            config.resolve.extensions = ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'];
            config.output.sourceMapFilename = "[name].js.map";
        }

        return config;
    },
    distDir: '../dist',
});

{
```

**.babelrc**

```
"presets": [
    "next/babel",
    "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
  ]
}
```

**app package.json**

```
{
      "name": "project",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "license": "UNLICENSED",
      "private": true,
      "description": "The project",
      "author": "author <author@example.com>",
      "browserslist": [
        "> 0.5%",
        "last 2 versions"
      ],
      "nodemonConfig": {
        "ignoreRoot": [
          ".git"
        ],
        "watch": [
          "src/server.js"
        ]
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@project/common": "*"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@zeit/next-typescript": "1.1.0"
      }
    }
```

**common lib package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@project/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "types": "./build/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "build/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "package:build:dev": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "@types/dateformat": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.3",
    "@types/hapi": "^17.0.19",
    "@types/hapi__basic": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/hapi__hapi": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/isomorphic-fetch": "^0.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.51",
    "@types/jsdom": "^16.2.3",
    "@types/memoizee": "^0.4.2",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.4",
    "@types/newrelic": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/next": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.7",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.4",
    "@types/styled-jsx": "^2.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
    "chokidar-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "clean-css-cli": "^4.1.5",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.9.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015.promise", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "@project/*": ["./node_modules"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use latest next (which supports TS) and https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I think you might be mixing up declaration files and source maps, so I just want to draw distinctions between the following:

- Declarations
- Declaration Maps
- Source Maps

[Declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration) files are files that end with `d.ts`. They describe an exported project's types and are consumed by TypeScript. They have nothing to do with the browser. For example, if you were to publish a TypeScript project to NPM, you'd usually compile it to JavaScript first, that way it's ready to import/execute into plain old JavaScript projects. But since you wrote the project in TypeScript, you probably want to expose all the TS goodness as well, so that's where declaration maps come in, they describe the types for the underlying JavaScript for other projects to consume.

[Source Maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#sourceMap) are a way to reconstruct minified JavaScript to assist debugging. They don't have anything to do with TypeScript, but if the JavaScript that they describe is generated by the TypeScript compiler, then it makes sense to have the compiler explain what the minified code is. That's why TypeScript's compiler has the option to export source maps.

Declaration files only expose an interface for other TypeScript modules/projects to correctly integrate your library, they don't expose the full source code for other developers to debug. For that, you need [Declaration Maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declarationMap). These are just like Source Maps but instead of describing your minified JavaScript as expanded JavaScript, they describe the original TypeScript, thus allowing you to debug a pre-compiled library as if it were TypeScript.

So in summary, to enable each of these you need to edit your *libraries* `tsconfig.json` and add one or more of the following:

```json
"declaration": true,
"declarationMap": true,
"sourceMap": true
```